# How to replace text in wordpress the_title?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to replace a text in wp title , 
Actually, There's a widget for popular posts. 
I want to replace a text in output of this widget, So I looked around the widget functions and I found this code :

```
foreach($popular as $post) :
        setup_postdata($post);
        ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php if ( $show_thumb3 == 1 ) : ?>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('widgetthumb',array('title' => '')); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php the_title(); ?>   
        </a>
blah blah blah...
```

I've tried to change this line `<?php the_title(); ?>` to :

```
<?php
    $wptitle = the_title();
    $wptitle = str_replace('textbefore', 'textafter', $wptitle);
    echo $wptitle;
?>
```

But it did nothing in the live site and nothing affected at all!
How can I replace a text in the title in widget output? 
How will it be possible if there are two strings that I want to replace ?
Should I use something like this ?:

```
    <?php
    $wptitle = the_title();
    $wptitle = str_replace('textbefore', 'textafter', $wptitle) && str_replace('text2before', 'text2after', $wptitle);
    echo $wptitle;
?>
```

Comment: the_title() function is used for display post title and that popular post plugin also display popular posts from post section so if you want to change something or want to add you can either append to the_title() or you needs to replace post title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$wptitle = the_title();
$wptitle = str_replace('textbefore', 'textafter', $wptitle);
echo $wptitle;
?>
```

**Replace with**

```
<?php
$wptitle = get_the_title($post->id);
$wptitle = str_replace('textbefore', 'textafter', $wptitle);
echo $wptitle;
?>
```

Comment: Works perfectly ! How will it be possible if there are two strings that I want to replace ? I used && but it returned 1, just 1 and nothing else.

Comment: didn't get you, please explain

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. It would be nice to have more info on the differences between these two methods ( get_the_title() vs the_title() ). I researched the wordpress codex and it seems they both return the title. Why does it work in this case ? thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$wptitle = get_the_title( get_the_ID() );
$wptitle = str_replace('textbefore', 'textafter', $wptitle);
echo $wptitle;
```